# SQL Searching Query using LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have implemented searching using Query having LIKE clause with % wild cards on both side.

I have column having names of countries. If I search with P or PAK it shows result But If I search it with 'I live in Pakistan' it doesn't compare.

The thing I understand is it matches with the sub string.

Is it possible to make its vice versa like I pass the string 'I live in Pakistan' and it matches with characters in fields and gets the result of Pakistan.

Instant help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and the query that you have tried would clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am using SELECT * FROM table WHERE country LIKE '%Pak%' 

It gives me right result and show all rows  having country Pakistan

But I want it to search while I compare it with 'I Love Pakistan' Because this sentence also contains Pakistan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the like()  function from codeigniter framework.

```
$this->db->like();
```

This function enables you to generate LIKE clauses, useful for doing searches.

> Note: All values passed to this function are escaped automatically.

Simple key/value method:
        $this->db->like('title', 'match');

```
    // Produces: WHERE title LIKE '%match%'
```

If you use multiple function calls they will be chained together with AND between them:

```
    $this->db->like('title', 'match');
    $this->db->like('body', 'match');

    // WHERE title LIKE '%match%' AND body LIKE '%match%
```

If you want to control where the wildcard (%) is placed, you can use an optional third argument. Your options are 'before', 'after' and 'both' (which is the default).

```
    $this->db->like('title', 'match', 'before');
    // Produces: WHERE title LIKE '%match'

    $this->db->like('title', 'match', 'after');
    // Produces: WHERE title LIKE 'match%'

    $this->db->like('title', 'match', 'both');
    // Produces: WHERE title LIKE '%match%'
```

If you do not want to use the wildcard (%) you can pass to the optional third argument the option 'none'.

```
    $this->db->like('title', 'match', 'none');
    // Produces: WHERE title LIKE 'match'
```

[See This](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

I think what you Need is to search and compare for every word in the provided text, i think this will be helpfull.

```
$temp = array();
$str = array();
$str = explode(' ', $string);
foreach ( $str as $word) {
    if (strlen($word) > 2) {
        $this->db->or_like('country_name', $word, 'both');
    } else {
        continue;
    }
}
$countries = $this->db->get('countries');
```

> i think in $countries you will have all the needed result.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the whitespaces with commas, and then use [`find_in_set`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set). Assuming your string is `$str`, consider this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   countries c
WHERE  c.name LIKE '%$str%' OR
       FIND_IN_SET(c.name, REPLACE($str, ' ', ',')) > 0
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing to one more function. :) Question: Is there way to flag/avoid use of 1 and 2 letter words in set?

Comment: @Tpojka not quite sure what you mean. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: If you check PHP solution I offered, there can be seen avoiding short words. For example `$value = "a country Serbia"` in my code `a` would be avoided since it could be found in many not-wanted results. Of course for country table is not much needed since it's contents are ~200 results, but asking for general purpose mysql way solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function searchCountry($value)
{
    $value = $value;
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE country LIKE '%$value%' ");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could work (disclaimer: not tested):

```
public function searchCountry($value)
{
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT FROM `countries`";

    $value = explode(' ', $value);// use all words from query
    $first_match = FALSE;
    foreach ($value as $k => $v)
    {
        if (strlen($v) >= 3)// exclude 1 and 2 letter words if want
        {
            if ( ! $first_match)
            {
                $sql .= " WHERE `name` LIKE %$v%";
            }
            else
            {
                $sql .= " OR `name` LIKE %$v%";
            }
        }
    }

    $sql .= " LIMIT 50";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

but you probably should use @Mureinik solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression trick for this purpose:

```
where country regexp replace($str, ' ', '|')
```

This constructs the expression:

```
where country regexp 'I|live|in|Pakistan'
```

which the evaluates to true because of the rules for regular expressions.